# Непонятные ошибки в простейшем окне (WinAPI на C++)

Tags: winapi, c++, visual-studio

Начал читать книгу Win32. Основы программирования. Финогенов. Там объясняется про программирование на C++ с помощью WinAPI. Переписал из книги программу, выводящую простейшее окно. Скомпилировал - выдает ошибку на счет несовпадения типов. В книге написано так же, как у меня в исходнике. Компилировал в Microsoft Visual C++ 2008. Ошибку не могу исправить. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<windowsx.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
    char szClassName[]="MainWindow";
    char szTitle[]="Программа 4-1";
    MSG Msg;
    WNDCLASS wc;
    ZeroMemory(&wc,sizeof(wc));
    wc.lpfnWndProc=WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.hIcon=LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor=LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground=GetStockBrush(LTGRAY_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszClassName=(LPCWSTR) szClassName;
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(szClassName, szTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 10, 10, 300, 100,
        HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, hInst, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0))
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg) {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        default:
            return (DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam));
    }
}
```

Вот та ошибка, которую выдает среда:

> `(23) : error C2664: CreateWindowExW: невозможно преобразовать параметр 2 из 'char [11]' в 'LPCWSTR';`

P.S. И почему в этой ошибке написано CreateWindowEx, хотя у меня в исходнике вызов CreateWindow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция CreateWindow требует строку LPCTSTR. Поэтому измените код так:

```
TCHAR szClassName[] = _T("MainWindow");
TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("Программа 4-1");
```

Перед сборкой проверьте включение заголовка:

```
#include <tchar.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

Финогенов писал под среду VC98. Почти наверняка.
Вариантов выхода из ситуации две - или использовать среду как у автора, или адаптировать пример. Новичкам проще первое, второе требует некоторых знаний, которых у Вас нет.

> CreateWindowExW

Для начала нужно понять, что в Windows существует две линейки функций - для работы со строчками со стандартными однобайтовыми символами (ASCII) и с двухбайтными символами (Unicode). Это помимо прочих извратов. И поэтому у многих ф-ций ОС есть два варианта. Они отличаются суффиксами. Так получаются CreateWindowExA и CreateWindowExW. Но чтобы программист не заморачивался можно вызывать просто [CreateWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680.aspx), а вызов конкретной ф-ции будет подставлен в зависимости от опций сборки проекта.

Далее рекомендую ознакомиться со строковыми типами. Например, [LPCWSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230352.aspx) - это "длинный" (Long) указатель (Pointer) на  константную (Const) строку (STRing) из двухбайтных "широких" (Wide) символов. И явно, что этот тип, ну, никак не совпадает и не преобразуется в / из char [11].

Вам нужно что-то изменить: или тип проекта, или заменить вызовы функций на необходимые, или привести строковые типы к нужным вариантам.

Вся необходимая Вам информация есть в справочной системе MSDN, доступной онлайн. Причем даже на русском языке.

Answer (score 1):

Меню Project -> [Имя проекта]Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Caracter Set выбираем Use Multi-Byte Character Set

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое решение (помимо предложенного khimiki) - написать

```
#undef UNICODE
```

перед

```
#include <windows.h>
```

И все...